# Getting location in xamarin forms in the background

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, location

I'm attempting to create a xamarin forms application which will get location updates and feed them to an HTTP endpoint. I'm having a great deal of difficulty understanding how to go about running a service in the background so that I continue to receive location information regardless of if the application is open or not especially in face of the change in API level 26 https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html.

I was using a LocationCallback when the application was in the foreground and that seemed to work okay but I'm wondering if just waking up from time to time and looking at `GetLastLocationAsync` or if that information is only updated when something actively requests location information.

What's the best way to implement a background service which will feed device location to an endpoint regardless of if the application is in the foreground?

Comment: I have never had to do the same before. But I guess, creating a sticky service and that polling the location service would do the trick for you. Have a look into https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny. This library has pretty much what you might need.

Comment: You can use [GeolocatorPlugin](https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/GeolocatorPlugin/BackgroundUpdates.html) and read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/) to learn about service in Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved it by registering another service and subscribed to location updates from within it.

```
using Xamarin.Essentials;

public class Service
{
    private IService service { get; }

    public Service(IService service)
    {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public async Task StartListening()
    {
        if (CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
            return;

        await CrossGeolocator.Current.StartListeningAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 10, true);

        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged += PositionChanged;
        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError += PositionError;
    }

    private void PositionChanged(object sender, PositionEventArgs e)
    {
        service.UpdateLocation(e.Position.Latitude, e.Position.Longitude);
    }

    private void PositionError(object sender, PositionErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        //Handle event here for errors
    }

    public async Task StopListening()
    {
        if (!CrossGeolocator.Current.IsListening)
            return;

        await CrossGeolocator.Current.StopListeningAsync();

        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionChanged -= PositionChanged;
        CrossGeolocator.Current.PositionError -= PositionError;
    }
}
```

}